# How do I add a progress bar in kotlin to thesame activity as the one for my google firebase login aunthentication

Tags: kotlin

Hey guys I'm trying to add a progressBar in kotlin to my Button so as soon as I hit the sign in button the progress bar automatically pops up and as soon as the data is fetched it should vanish automatically
... Plus I have it in my activity thesame activity where the code of my Google sign in aunthentication is writing And assigned to a button

So how do I go about assigning the progressBar to the same button please help